# Adding line numbers to output file in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have the information from an input file being stored in a buffer. The buffer is then printed into an output file. Since the buffer stores the whole text file, how could I go about adding line numbers before each individual line of text? For example, if the input file contained:

dog
cat

Then I would want the output file to contain:

1. dog
2. cat

I have the input and output working fine, it's just the line number part that is throwing me off.

Comment: Print the line numbers separately. You are not required to use a single write for a line.

Answer (score 1):

Output is a serialization of characters.  Any approach that will result in the desired character sequence will work.

You can insert line numbers into the text buffer with the idea of printing the entire buffer including line numbers, to the output file in one go.

Or you can print piece parts of the input text, alternated by line numbers.

For example print one character at a time, and when you get to a newline character in the input, print a line number to the output after printing that input character.

Comment: How would I go about inserting line numbers into the text buffer? The idea makes sense but I don't know even know where to begin. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Like I said, you can read one character at a time from the input file, and write it to the output file.  If that character is a newline, then take a pause reading from the input and send a line number to the output, then resume with the input...